# How to redirect from magento 2 checkout page to the 3rd party payment gateway api?

Tags: magento2, php, api, payment-gateway

I am working on the Magento 2 payment gateway. The backend is completed but in frontend we stuck for getting the Magento 2 customer detail and post it to our 3rd party API. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

To implement payment gateway on Magento 2, I would recommend you to use the following reference:

http://inchoo.net/magento-2/implementing-payment-gateway-magento-2/

This is simple in words and also a best solution to solve your problem.

Comment: I already read it it is not working position and it is based on filling card details on magento end i want to make redirection based payment gateway

Comment: @AyushMittal this is exactly what you need, POST the customer data by using hidden html form. Here is the complete reference:
http://www.junaidbhura.com/how-to-make-a-custom-magento-payment-extension-for-an-external-gateway/

Comment: This solution is not for the magento 2 :(

Comment: @AyushMittal then I would suggest using an API based method which POST customer data using CURL method in PHP. Follow the link as I tested this method personally in different areas of development:

http://excellencemagentoblog.com/blog/2012/05/01/magento-create-custom-payment-method-api-based/

Comment: @ Fayyaz i already implemented all magento 1.x methods but in magento 2.0 it doesn't works :( you share me doc of magento 1.x not for magento 2.0

Comment: @AyushMittal Well this may be the possibility magento is still thinking something about it. Lets see what comes up next. Below is not the official way but you may try it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33416686/magento-2-no-redirect-to-external-payment-provder

Comment: @ Fayyaz i will definately try it thanks for it revert it to back

Comment: @AyushMittal Your welcome :)

Comment: @ Fayyaz i didn't work :( try something else